# Input impedance, on-state loss, and switching loss of MOSFET and BJT

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, bjt

1. Why does a BJT have a low input impedance comparison to a MOSFET, and has low conduction loss and high switching loss?
2. Why does a MOSFET have high conduction loss and low switching loss?
3. What are the advantages of the high input impedance of a MOSFET?

Comment: Some of these answers are found by googling so, what have you uncovered so far?

Comment: The reason MOSFET has high input impedance because gate is isolated from source to drain channel. The high input impedance of mosfet needs low gate drive current ( which i didn't get). Switching is fast in MOSFET comparison with BJT so switching loss is less in MOSFET than BJT. I couldn't understand how BJT has low input impedance and has low on state loss.

Comment: I wouldn't say that MOSFETs have high conduction loss. I would say they have lower conduction loss in all but the highest current applications.

Comment: What is the meaning of Mosfet having high input impedance needs lower gate drive ?

Comment: If you can provide some context -- such as, if this is for homework, what background material has been covered in preparation for these questions? -- more meaningful answers can be provided.  As-is, the questions seem to assume things that either aren't true *anymore*, or aren't true *in general*.